# Action bar list navigation + tab navigation - Position of spinner is not at left most

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

According to Jake as in  [Android layout with action bar and tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034063/android-layout-with-action-bar-and-tabs), we decide to follow his 2nd suggestion.

**Use tab navigation in the action bar and set a custom view with a Spinner**

Together with [IcsSpinner](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/library/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/IcsSpinner.java) from ActionBarSherlock itself, we manage to make it work in Gingerbread and ICS both.

However, we still suffer the following problem, during landscape mode.

[image]

Note, the spinner ("Portfolio 1") is in between PORTFOLIO tab and search icon. What we want is, the spinner is at the left side of WATCHLIST tab.

Is there anything we may try out?

Thanks.

Comment: I am still facing this issue - did you get a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You can set custom view for your action bar, user RelativeLayout to put your spinner at left side of "WATCH LiST"

in java code: actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar_layout)

Comment: That's the problem - unable to set the custom view to left of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

a very late answer, but this is possible. You just have to replace (programatically) the view that is pointed by `android.R.id.action_bar_title` with a `Spinner`. I wrote a blog about it. Here's the [link](http://www.hasnath.net/blog/actionbar-tab-spinnerlist-navigation-at-the-same-time)