# Android action bar list navigation stops working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, viewpagerindicator

I am using ActionBarSherlock and ViewPagerIndicator to create an activity that has both tabs and list navigation.

The tabs are backed by a FragmentStatePagerAdapter and allow the user to navigate between the different sections of the app.  The list navigation allows the user to toggle the view mode of the tab they are currently on e.g. if they are viewing search results they are able to toggle between list and grid mode.

The problem that I am having is that when i scroll between the tabs the list navigation intermittently stops working. I can click on the spinner and it displays the list of options but when i select one of them the text in the spinner:

- Doesn't get updated,
- onNavigationItemSelected() doesn't get called.

(For some reason using a FragmentPagerAdapter rather than a FragmentStatePagerAdapter seems to stop the issue occurring as frequently but it still happens occasionally.)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem, except I only have one View in my ViewPager so no swiping occurs.  My View contains a GridView and when calling notifyDatasetChanged() on it's adapter the list navigation no longer works.  Seems like the ActionBar is losing it's reference to the OnNavigationListener though can't see how.

Comment: I have the same problem combining list navigation with tabs. For me I have isolated the issue to tabs that contain a SherlockListFragment. As soon as this fragment is opened in a tab the OnNavigationListeners stops functioning. If I have the same fragment directly in the list-navigation (not in a tab) there is no problem.

Comment: This might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11036562/969325

Answer (score 0):

I think should not use the tab navigation built in the ActionBar.

You can use the PagerTitle interface that is available in ViewPager. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html

Or you can use the below great libraries
http://viewpagerindicator.com
https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip