# Progress Dialog not aligned in the ActionBarSherlock after API Level 11+

Tags: android, themes, actionbarsherlock, progressdialog

In my Project i have add Library ActionBar Sherlock and create the custom theme for my project.

I have created custom theme from [here](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/).
But after applying the theme my Progress Dialog in not aligned(means not displayed in the center of screen).

Please not this issue appears in API Level 11 or above.
Here i have attached the screen shot of emulator running OS 4.2.2.

I am unable to figure out this issue...

**ScreenShot ::**

[image]

**MyCustomTheme ::(values folder)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <style name="Theme.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_exampthemesherlocklightle</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_exampthemesherlocklightle</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_exampthemesherlocklightle</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_exampthemesherlocklightle</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_exampthemesherlocklightle</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_exampthemesherlocklightle</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_exampthemesherlocklightle</item>
        <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_exampthemesherlocklightle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_exampthemesherlocklightle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_exampthemesherlocklightle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_exampthemesherlocklightle</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_exampthemesherlocklightle</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_exampthemesherlocklightle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_exampthemesherlocklightle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_exampthemesherlocklightle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Sherlock.Translucent" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Translucent" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml ::**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Custom_ThemeSherlockLight" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testproject.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ProgressDialog pDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog =ProgressDialog.show(this,null, "Please Wait..", true);
        pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**progress.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Please wait.."
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the following lines of code in

> progress.xml file

```
android:layout_width="130dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

It should display in the center of the screen now.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** Please change the layout_width attribute of TextView to "wrap_content".

Comment: Bingo !!!!!!! Solved... But if i run after applying your changes,then text view display only half(instead of display "please wait.." it display only "Please").

Comment: I have tested it on device running Android 4.0.4 and I can see the complete text "Please wait...". Let me know your test environment.

Comment: Please change the layout_width attribute of TextView to "wrap_content". It should work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps or not. But to fix the cropping issue of "Please wait" text. Change the layout_width to "wrap_content" like this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Please wait.."
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```